# Highcharts: phantomjs export image missing labels

Tags: highcharts

My chart is a stacked bar chart with requirements to have data labels on the actual bars.

The in browser version is working perfectly featuring the data labels accordingly, however the exported image does not have them.

Here is my code:

```
{
  colors: ['#0EAC55','#91C855','#F3BA0E','#F39595','#F30E0E'],
       chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                height: 195
            },
            credits: {
            enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3'],
            },
             tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '%'
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                max: 100,
                opposite: true,
            },
            legend: {
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    stacking: 'percent',
                    groupPadding: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000'

                    }
                }
            },
                series: [{"name":"5","legendIndex":5,"data":[41.1,44.2,60.2]},{"name":"4","legendIndex":4,"data":[42.9,38.4,25.2]},{"name":"3","legendIndex":3,"data":[12.2,12,8.8]},{"name":"2","legendIndex":2,"data":[3.3,5,3]},{"name":"1","legendIndex":1,"data":[1,1,3.3]}]
    }
```

I am using the phantomjs server to produce images as these need to be generated on the server side. http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-articles/news/56-improved-image-export-with-phantomjs/

Comment: working on my side http://jsfiddle.net/huAuh/ ... Can you create a fiddle for us?

Comment: Actually made the fiddle myself with your code, and it is still working on my side. http://jsfiddle.net/huAuh/1/.. I download as JPEG and I can see the lables in the bars

Comment: As mentioned in the post title, I am using phantomjs server to export the chart. In browser the chart displays correctly. My charts are to be generated every day automatically with no browser involved. I have taken your code from js fiddle and passed it to the phantomjs server and this is what is produced: http://s28.postimg.org/nzz2h7vu5/bar.png

Comment: @Ash Did you solve this issue? I have the same issue now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried all options above. Set all `animation` options to `false`, all `defer` options to `false`, but it didn't help me to solve the problem.

Finally I found an issue on [github.com](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3159). And it was a bug of **HighCharts**. I was using `4.0.1` version of `Highcharts`.

So, the solution is just to update your highcharts file to the lastest version if the suggestions above didn't work.

My sample code can be found on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6dppfLm/).

Answer (score 0):

Disable all animations, and make sure you have up-to-date exporting server, not some old one.

Also, set [defer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.dataLabels.defer) options to false.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer given by Pawel Fus, I found that making sure animation was set to false did make a difference, but not the at the overall level (i.e. `chart.animation = false`), it had to be set on  `chart.plotOptions.series.animation = false`.