# Highcharts convert: not showing pie chart data labels

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs, highcharts-convert

I'm using PhantomJS with Highcharts and Highcharts convert to render charts on a server. I'm attempting to render a pie chart with data labels enabled. My configuration JSON works fine when run in a browser, but the same JSON with PhantomJS omits the data labels. Everything else rendered is correct.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    chart: {
        height:500,
        type: 'pie',
    },
    legend: {
        margin: 30
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            showInLegend: true,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y} ({point.percentage:.1f}%)',
            },
        }
    },
    series:     
[{
    name: 'Count',
    data: [

            ['A', 12 ]

                ,

            ['B', 500 ]

                ,

            ['C', 50 ]

    ]
}]


}
```

Here's a link to a JSFiddle with the same JSON, which works correctly:

https://jsfiddle.net/j2nb72L7/

Here is the image output from PhantomJS:

[image]

Comment: When you use phantomjs *only* the labels are missing? The data is plotted/drawed correctly?

Comment: @JoseGarrido yes, the data itself is fine. You can compare the image posted to the fiddle to see what I mean.

Comment: I think that this topic may be connected with your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633441/highcharts-phantomjs-export-image-missing-labels

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Thanks, you're correct. This was caused by a bug in Highcharts. Upgrading to the latest version fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the version of Highcharts being used. I was using v4.0.1, upgrading to v4.2.5 fixed it.